# localization preserves free finite resolution?

Tags: commutative-algebra

If any finite generated module over ring $R$ has a finite free resolution. Is it true that any finite generated module over $S^{-1}R$ has a finite free resolution ?

If it's not please give me a counterexample.

Thanks.

Comment: Every $S^{-1}R$-module has the form $S^{-1}M$ with $M$ an $R$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over the localization. It contains an $R$-submodule $N$ which is finitely generated and whose localization is precisely $M$ itself. The hypothesis implies that $N$ has a finite free resolution. Localizing that resolution gives you a finite free resolution of $M$.